# How to Create a PNG image using just notepad?

Tags: png, notepad

As we know, all files are simply containers for data. `PNG` files are no exception to this rule.

A PNG file basically just refers to a rectangular grid of colored pixels, so it can't be that complicated - certainly not as complicated as a video or even a GIF.

My question is, how can you create a PNG from nothing, using just notepad? This file could then be opened in a browser (such as Chrome) which would recognize it as an image.

A tiny square of four colored pixels would serve as a great example.

Using Paint to attempt to see what's going yields interesting results.

If Paint is used to create a PNG file that looks like this, (it's very small, 2x2 pixels, so you might need to zoom in)

[image]

The resultant text file looks like this:

`` IHDR         ýÔšs   sRGB ®Îé   gAMA  ±üa     pHYs  Ã  ÃÇo¨d   IDATWcè`ýÿ‰Ai£½Ç !ß=î_—    IEND®B`‚ ``

But what is going on behind the scenes?

To clarify, the question is not how to create any PNG file, but how to, using text, create a PNG file matching certain criteria, for example, a line of 7 colors of the rainbow?

Comment: Can you not just open `Paint` > `File` > `Save As` > `PNG Picture` and then open it to see a blank PNG file with one big white square with apps. Just press the `Win Key` one time and type `Paint`, once it pops up, just follow those instruction.

Comment: That is a very good idea, I will give it a shot

Comment: I added the output from Paint, any insights?

Comment: See my instructions in my answer for step-by-step and try it that way and then report back your results... what are you opening the PNG file with application wise?

Comment: Please check out the updated question

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Comment: @jcbermu Extremely helpful!

Comment: It might be easier to make a bmp? png uses compression so it might be dynamic the way its file looks no?

Comment: `A PNG file basically just refers to a rectangular grid of colored pixels, so it can't be that complicated` png is a compressed format, and compressed files are never simple

Comment: It's important to remember the differences between 'test' and 'binary' data... notepad cannot faithfully represent or handle 'binary' data.

Comment: Use the text editor to write some PHP (or other language) code that creates a PNG and draws on it, etc. :)

Answer (score 6):

#### How can I create a PNG from nothing, using just Notepad?

With great difficulty. It would be easier (but still difficult) using a hex editor.

Essentially you have to create a file in a format that matches the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/).

The header of the file must start with a PNG signature, which consists of the following decimal values:

```
137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
```

Decimal 10 (a linefeed) cannot be entered using Notepad (hence the suggestion of using a Hex Editor) to create the file.

You also need to be able to calculate CRC values and follow lots of complicated Chunk Ordering Rules.

If you read the spec linked above you will see how complicated it is to create a PNG by hand.

It would be much easier to use a Graphics Editor that supports PNG.

Comment: PGP signature? Are you referring to the magic header?

Answer (score 3):

Just open up [Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint) by pressing the Windows Flag key [image] one time and then start typing in `Paint`; once it pops up from the menu just click on it to launch the app.

[image]

Now with a blank paint screen open, you can create color filled squares, etc. for your needs, and then when you're ready to save it as a `PNG` file you just go to  <kbd>**`File`**</kbd> **|** <kbd>**`Save As`**</kbd> **|** <kbd>**`PNG Picture`**</kbd> and then open it to see the image with the app from the saved location.

---

> ### Create a 4x4 pixel square with 4 different 1 pixel colored squares
>
> With [Paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint) opened and
>   starting with a blank image. . .
>
> 1. From the <kbd>**`Home`**</kbd> tab press the <kbd>**`Resize`**</kbd> option
> 2. In the **`Resize and Skew`** window adjust the **`Horizontal and Vertical`** by **`Pixes`**  [image]
> 3. With the **`Pencil`** [image] tool, you can change the color to your desired color and then fill in
>      the 4x4 pixel square in with 4 different colored 1 pixel squares. 
>      [image]
> 4. Now go to <kbd>**`File`**</kbd> **|** <kbd>**`Save As`**</kbd> **|** <kbd>**`PNG Picture`**</kbd> and then open it to see the image with the app from the saved location.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! I've updated the question, please have a look at the updated text.

Comment: Sadly this is not at all what is asked, it does not provide any info for synthesizing new PNGs

Answer (score 3):

Here is what the "text" of a simple png image looks like

[image]

This data comes from the simple picture below.

[image]

As such, you can't create a PNG image file just by putting it's "text" into a document unless the text editor you are using can handle the special characters and not destroy the metadata (like notepad++). You can't actually type the "code" for a png file either, as its "syntax" is too complex for a keyboard of any sort.

Here's what happens when you try:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried copy and pasting that "stuff" you find opening the picture in notepad, and putting it in a new notepad file , saving as png?

Comment: It does not work like that. As I said, notepad can't handle the character encoding that comes in a PNG file. You would have to use a text editor like Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and even then, you would ONLY be able to copy/paste because you can't "type" an image file.

Comment: I've added a picture to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually files are not just containers for data. They are a stream of binary data. Every file type has a different lay out of what parts of the binary stream is what data.

Opening an image in notepad will cause the binary stream to be interpreted as characters in human language. However, we do not make files using binary that corresponds to what we defined to be characters in a particular language of speech. Therefore notepad may or may not you with any useful interpretation of the binary stream to be able to add and remove data recognizeable to a PNG interpreter.

If you truly are curious as to how to create PNG files from nothing, you have to do it using numbers (most preferrably binary or hexadecimal), using a hex editor program that reads the binary stream from the disk and displays it in base 16 for you.

Please see [DavidPostill's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1191256/596755)

Comment: If I mis-used binary stream and it's actually a byte stream could someone please edit my question